# Neo4j count appearances of friends of friends

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I want to find out all the FoF I have, and for each one, through how many friends I'm connected to him.

I already got the FOFs:

> MATCH (me {id:123})-[:friend]->(friend:User)<-[:friend]-(fofs:User)
>
> WHERE NOT (me:User)-[:friend]->(fofs:User)
>
> RETURN fofs

But how do I "group by" and count?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to group by `fofs` and then get the `friend` count per group:

```
MATCH (me:User {id:123})-[:friend]->(friend:User)<-[:friend]-(fofs:User)
WHERE NOT (me)-[:friend]->(fofs)
RETURN fofs, COUNT(friend);
```